# FlywayException: Invalid migration state 'ignored'. Valid states are: [*, missing, pending, ıgnored, future]

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to run spring boot application using flyway and Mysql database. When I run the application,   I'm getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid migration state 'ignored'. Valid states are: [*, missing, pending, ıgnored, future]
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.pattern.ValidatePattern.fromPattern(ValidatePattern.java:70) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ValidatePatternUtils.lambda$isIgnoredIgnored$3(ValidatePatternUtils.java:31) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:632) ~[na:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ValidatePatternUtils.isIgnoredIgnored(ValidatePatternUtils.java:31) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoContext.isIgnoredIgnored(MigrationInfoContext.java:43) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoImpl.validate(MigrationInfoImpl.java:251) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.validate(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:511) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.lambda$validate$0(DbValidate.java:111) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:55) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:101) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:365) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.lambda$migrate$0(Flyway.java:133) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:196) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:129) ~[flyway-core-9.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
  <groupId>net.sayilir</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-application</name>
    <description>An example project demonstrates testing Spring Kafka</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <flyway.version>9.14.1</flyway.version>
        <flyway.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</flyway.url>
        <flyway.user>***</flyway.user>
        <flyway.password>***</flyway.password>
    </properties>
```

I try to clean or repair but it doesn't work

```
./mvnw flyway:clean
```

```
./mvnw flyway:repair
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have encountered [bug #3616](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3616) in Flyway, and also that you are using the Turkish locale. This bug reports the exact same behaviour that you are seeing.

You are using Flyway 9.14.1. Try updating Flyway to version 9.15 or later.